# All Reviewers Assigned : Nature Communications revised manuscript: What does it means?

Tags: journals, peer-review, paper-submission

I have a revised manuscript which I submitted to Nature Communications. The status of the manuscript says 'Reviewers Assigned' for about 24 days. What does it mean? Is it under review by the reviewers? Or reviewers are not responding to the editor after the request to review the revised manuscript by the editor? Just want to clarify, that this question is specific to the editorial process of 'Nature Communications' which is not usual and not related to generalized peer review process. I think I am asking this question especially because Nature Journals have their own editorial workflow which is not as same a typical workflow of many journals.

Comment: Update on the question. After being under the status 'All reviewers assigned', the manuscript status changed back to 'Manuscript Under consideration'. 
This is more confusing as generally, 'Manuscript Under consideration' means that the editor is considering the manuscript for peer review. Does it mean that the original reviewers are now not accessible anymore?

Comment: Another update: I got an update from the editor finally after email her asking what it really means. The manuscript was under review when it was showing 'all reviewers assigned' and when the status changed to 'under consideration' it means that reviews are back with her and she is discussing it with her collegues.

Answer (score 1):

It means reviewers have been invited, but you can't read anything more than that. Whether or not reviewers have accepted the invitation is usually confidential information available only to journal staff. Depending on the range of statuses the journal uses, this status might even mean that some reviews have been received.

In any case, there's nothing to do except wait and see.

Answer (score 0):

It can mean many things, if the status has been same since you resubmitted your manuscript then editor might still be waiting for all the reviewers to send the editors their review reports, in some cases when one reviewer is too much busy and needs more time to finalize his review report, editors waits for him to send his comments then they contact the author and make a decision on the basis of these reports and send you acceptance, rejection or revision based on their reports.

Also if one reviewers has recommended for rejection and one or two reviewers has endorsed the publication then editor weighs the comments of all the reviewers and then make the final decision.